# What size crimp connector for 2.54mm headers?

Tags: connector

I have a few pin headers on my board which are the standard 2.54mm spaced pins ([datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1518407.pdf)), and I'm trying to find the appropriate female crimp connector which will connect to it, exactly like the one below:

[image]

However, I'm having trouble determining the size of the crimp connector. The datasheet says that the male header is 1.1mm, so 17 AWG.

What is the size and shape (and hopefully if known, the name) of the crimp connector I need?

Comment: What is the number of position are you looking for?

Comment: @SanjeevKumar Sorry, I don't understand your question

Comment: Position means number of contact. Like 10 Pin contact or 20 Pin contact. If you will check the datasheet, in description column it is mentioned 2 ways,3 ways...etc.

Comment: @SanjeevKumar I'm after the size and name of the single crimp connector inside one of those black enclosures in the picture.

Comment: AWG Rating can be determine based on the current rating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the below connector

http://uk.farnell.com/fci/65039-036lf/connector-receptacle-2-54mm-1way/dp/2112430

And for crimp

http://uk.farnell.com/fci/47745-001lf/crimp-socket-22-26awg/dp/1097977?MER=en-me-pd-r2-acce-con